# I Have one for condition, and can't do if statement to count cell condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to do this condition to count how many times (cells) have values less than 300 seconds (5 minutes) but it returns me an error, the condition is about a DF below, that I pull from my csv:

```
df =
    0
0   NaN
1   79.0
2   140.0
3   131.0
4   72.0
... ...
16341   349.0
16342   795.0
16343   787.0
16344   410.0
16345   1221.0
```

I try this way:

```
for key, value in data_df.items() :
  df = data_df[key].fillna(0, inplace=False).astype(int)   
  if key <= 300 :
   df_count = value.count( value.values() <= 300)
   display(df_count)
```

but the error message says:

> TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

How can I solve my `IF` statement to execute the `Display()` code?

**EDITED FOR BETTER RESULTS**

I Should asked this before but i thought that the sollution would be alike `IF` statement.

I need to make it in range, the condition is to count every cell in a range about 5 to 5 minutes, untill I get 1 hour complete, So the conditions is about:

1. 0 to 300 (5minutes)
2. 300 to 600 (5 to 10 minutes)
3. 600 to 900 (10 minutes to 15 minutes)

.
.
.

until i get one hour complete, I tryed:
`df_count300to600 = data_df[key].fillna(0).le( key > 300 && key< 600 )`

How can I solve at this point?

Comment: Can you explain what are the "cells" and duration in your data? Wouldn't `df[0].le(300).sum()` give you the expected result?

Comment: the cells are seconds in face to face service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you just need:

```
count = df[0].fillna(0).le(300).sum()
```

Example output: `5`

###### How it works

`df[0].fillna(0).le(300)` creates a boolean Series, `sum` counts the `True`:

```
            0  df['0'].fillna(0).le(300)
0         NaN                       True
1        79.0                       True
2       140.0                       True
3       131.0                       True
4        72.0                       True
16341   349.0                      False
16342   795.0                      False
16343   787.0                      False
16344   410.0                      False
16345  1221.0                      False
```

##### edited question:

You might need to use `cut`:

```
pd.cut(df[0].fillna(0), bins=[0, 300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500]).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
(0, 300]        4
(300, 600]      2
(600, 900]      2
(1200, 1500]    1
(900, 1200]     0
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Or with arithmetics:

```
df[0].fillna(0).floordiv(300).add(1).mul(300).value_counts()
```

Output:

```
300.0     5
600.0     2
900.0     2
1500.0    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This won't include the NaN in the count, which I assume is required, so you'd still need `df[0].fillna(0, inplace=False).le(300).sum()`

Comment: @MattPitkin well spotted, I forgot about the `fillna` from OP's code!

Comment: it didn't work... error like: "'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'fillna'"

Comment: well, i tryed again and worked! thanks!

Comment: what actually well worked was this one: `count = df[key].fillna(0).le(300).sum()`

Comment: @MattPitkin I edited the question, could help me one more time, please?

Comment: @Felipe sure I'm willing to help, but please do not modify questions and unaccept to gain attention, this is not how this site works. This is not a customer service but rather a collections of Q/A. If you must modify the question, then maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: @mozway, sorry for that, but as I edited de question i though that it work like that, sorry again for my mistake! thanks for clarifying!